# Locally presentable categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monads, locally-presentable-categories

1. Under category

Let $C$ be a locally presentable category, and let $c$ be an object of $C$. Lets denote by $C^{/c}$ the under category, objects are maps $c\rightarrow x$ and morphisms are the evident ones. I was wondering if the category $C^{/c}$  is also locally presentable ?

2. Monad

Let $T$ be a monad on a locally presentable category $C$. Under which condition the category of $T$-algebras (the category of algebras over the monad $T$) is a locally presentable? Examples are very welcome.

Comment: Over and under categories of a presentable category are presentable. This is Proposition 1.57 in [Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/locally-presentable-and-accessible-categories/94CB48295B6AF097FC232313A57BDE17). If $T : C \to C$ preserves $\lambda$-directed colimits and $C$ is $\lambda$-presentable, then the category of $T$-algebras is also $\lambda$-presentable. This is proved in 2.78 in the same book. A monad preserves $\lambda$-directed colimits if and only if it corresponds to a $\lambda$-infinitary algebraic theory.

Comment: @ValeryIsaev thanks for the references! You should put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Over and under categories of a presentable category are presentable. This is Proposition 1.57 in Adámek, Rosický, Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories.
2. If $T : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ preserves $\lambda$-directed colimits and $\mathcal{C}$ is $\lambda$-presentable, then the category of $T$-algebras is also $\lambda$-presentable. This is proved in 2.78 in the same book. A monad preserves $\lambda$-directed colimits if and only if it corresponds to a $\lambda$-infinitary algebraic theory.